# Google Form with and URL within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, url

Sorry if this has been answered before, I am not very good at how to explaining what's in my head into words.

I currently have a Google Form, where on submit a user is redirected to a specific URL once the answers have been supplied (using the addon Formfacade).

This will work perfectly for English reading users, but going forward I want to be able to redirect to a specific url based on the language they required via the form/sheet.

Within Google Sheet, I have a cell that contains the URL based upon the newest time stamp entry & language.

Is there a way I can create a short url (for the on submit button, redirect in Form), that reads the url of the cell which has just been amended, to display the correct local language site?

I have tried the Google sheets "get link to this cell" but that just returns the Google Sheet.

Comment: The redirection is triggered by `Formfacade` so I can't see how Google Sheets is relevant. OTOH, "Formfacade" says you can use `conditional logic based on form responses to show different pages`. May I suggest that your question is about the operation of "Formfacade" rather than Googe Sheets.